# Resetear/limpiar el modal al cerrar bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Dentro de una pagina levanto un modal que carga contenido de una carpeta, pdf, imagenes, el problema es que al cerrarlo y volver a abrir para que traiga otros datos del mismo directorio se queda con cierta información del modal anterior, mismos tabs en algunos casos, a raiz de esto busco la forma de resetearlo al cerrar dicho modal.

tengo estas lineas de codigo sobre como lo genero:

```
<div class="btnModal" id="l1">108</div>

<!--   Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalf2">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">              
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    De no existir ocultar este tab
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
                      <div class="modalbutton">
                        <div>
                        <p class="circModalBtn">
                          <i class="fa fa-object-group fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h4>Insctrucción</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">
                      <div class="modalbutton">
                        <div>
                          <i class="fa fa-flag-o fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h4>Detalles</h4></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">
                      <div class="modalbutton">
                        <div>
                          <i class="fa fa-folder-o fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h4>Resumen</h4></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="example-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#example" role="tab" aria-controls="example" aria-selected="false">
                      <div class="modalbutton">
                        <div>
                          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-2x margenmodal alignicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h4>Ejemplos</h4></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">     
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" style="vertical-align: top;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="example" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="example-tab">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
function fileCheck(file, callbackSi, callbackNo) {
$.ajax({
    url: file,
    type: 'HEAD',
    error: function() {
        // El archivo no existe, ejecutar función
        callbackNo();
    },
    success: function() {
        // El archivo sí existe
        callbackSi();
    }
});
}

let sections = {
  home: 'instruccion',
  profile: 'glosario',
  contact: 'declaraciones',
  example: 'ejemplo'
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnModal').click(function() {
    // obtener ID
    let id = this.id;
    // Recorrer arreglo con ID de contenedor para verificar
    Object.keys(sections).forEach(section => {
        // Crear nombre de archivo
        let file = `./files/${id}/${id}_${sections[section]}.pdf`;
        // Verificar que existe archivo
        fileCheck(file,
            // Función a ejecutar si existe el archivo
            () => {
                // Mostrar PDF
                $('#' + section).html(`<embed src="${file}#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px" class="margenfilemodal" />`)
                console.log("Se ha clickeado el id " +this.id);
            },
            // Función a ejecutar si no existe el archivo
            () => {
                // Simplemente ocultar sección
                $('#' + section).hide();
                console.log('No existe el archivo para la sección: ' + section);
            });
    });
  });
});
```

el problema surge al cerrar y volver a abrir, me carga información de otro modal abierto anteriormente. probe con algunas funciones como las siguientes, pero aún asi me sucede el mismo problema:

```
$(this).find('form2')[0].reset();
```

```
$("#myBtn").click(function() {
document.getElementById("form2").reset();
  $("#edit-modal").modal();
});
```

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    console.log('Hi *');
    $("#myModal-event .modal-body").html(' Loading... ');
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');

});
```

a modo de ejemplo con ninguna logro lo que necesito... claro esta modificando en cada una de ellas los id modal correspondientes.

Comment: Dentro del ciclo, antes de definirla variable `file` intenta borrar el contenido de cada sección con `$('#' + section).html();`. Si no funciona, quizá el tengas más de una ventana modal; solo debería haber una.

Comment: la verdad probe asi pero no me sirve, porque al cerrar limpia pero al ir a seleccionar otro id y abrir no cargan mas datos en el modal...

Comment: Es solo un codigo para el modal, este modal a traves de javascript me levanta aprox 100 modales se podria decir, esos cargan información desde un directorio o carpeta... no quiero decir que levanto 100 modales en un click por si acaso.
a ver me explico algo mas, tengo una index.html, dentro de ella un formulario, ese formulario tiene cientos de lineas, dichas lineas contienen su div, al cual le di un id,  al darle click al div en base al id me busca en carpeta si hay algo con ese id que coincida, luego carga la info en distintos tabs y cierro el modal

Comment: luego doy click a otro div que tiene otro id y levanta otro modal, aqui el problema es que ya no me levanta los mismos tabs, me levanta 1 o 2 en el modal, siendo que hay mas contenido en el directorio... por esa razón busco limpiar

Comment: no son 100 modales, es uno solo tal cual como ves en el codigo que puse arriba amigo, y actualiza el contenido a medida que recibe el click, a medida que le doy click a un div u otro... el problema como dije es que al cerrar este modal con id 1 que contiene 4 tabs por ejemplo y quiero cargar el 5 que contiene 3 tabs me muestra 2, y si quiero cargar el id 10 me muestra 2 tabs, esto a modo de ejemplo lo digo dentro de los 100 directorios distintos por llamarlo asi a los que consulta el codigo.

Comment: por eso la idea es o refrescar los nuevos tabs o limpiar y al hacer click al proximo id que eliga me cargue ese nuevo contenido, pero no logro que funcione asi

Comment: Dentro de la función agregar `console.log(this.id);` para confirmar que es correcto y corresponde al elemento en que haces clic. Después de definir el archivo también muéstralo en consola: `console.log(file);` y edita la pregunta para poner el resultado de ambas.